# Installing T&G engineered hardwood floor glue assist vs full spread

Tags: flooring

This floor will be installed on plywood which will sit on diagonal boards sitting on the joists. The installer is suggesting brackets and glue assist.

Here is the the hardwood I am buying:
The boards are [Coswick Aqua White, 7" wide](https://www.coswick.com/pdf/Signature-Oak-Aqua-White-T01-Silk-mat-S&B-en.pdf) (PDF).

Here is a link to the two glue assist methods
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDsMY_sXfjc
The installer sent me a picture showing the one where the glue is spread using a trowel not the one using the gun

Comment: Do the installation instructions allow for either option? That strikes me as unusual as most floors these days are floating and the only option is whether the pieces click together or need to be glued together, not glued to the floor. Also, where do the brackets come into play? Granted, I'm not _super_ familiar with floating floors, but I've also never heard of any bracketry involved.

Comment: I think it is staples but he called them brackets (the invoice says nail-down with glue assist. This is tong and groove as the title says. I don't think that tongue and groove is floating. The nail/staple goes through the tongue at 45 degrees and then into the floor, I think you know that, what confused you was the word brackets (might be my mistake). I added the link the what I am buying

Comment: Confusion was mine - we see so many floating floor questions and so few real hardwood floor questions that I just assumed. My bad. Maybe I picked up on "floating floor" from an existing answer, too. In what way would the glue be used to "assist" the installation? Glue on the T&G? A stripe of glue on the back of each board instead of a full coat of glue on each board? More clarity there would help.

Comment: I added some comments to the initial post see there.

Answer (score 0):

A full spread glued down floor will be a better floor. It is less movement prone and more moisture resistant (because of the glued bottom surface). Downside is that it is considerably more expensive to install labor and material wise.

There is absolutely nothing wrong with a glue together "floating floor". Installation goes faster and materials are less expensive (saves $). Usually a foam underlayment is required which does cost. Also, removal in the future is very much easier compared to a full spread glued down floor.

It is really your decision.

Comment: I am not following you. This is not a floating floor if glued and nailed (braketed) down is it?

Comment: Yes, I made the mistake of thinking I knew what is was you were asking.